# How Node.js silently crashes without any information?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sftp, ssh-tunnel

Application silently dies when it opens a lot of SFTP connections. I use all sorts of `process` event handlers and the only one triggered is `process.on('exit',...`

I'm using an npm package for SFTP `ssh2-sftp-client` which is using `ssh2` package underneath.

### Here is a minimal reproducible code

```js
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')
const inspect = require('util').inspect

const sftpClient = new Client();

sftpClient.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('SFTP client emitted ERROR: ' + inspect(err))
})
sftpClient.on('end', () => {
  console.log('SFTP client emitted END')
})
sftpClient.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('SFTP client emitted FINISH')
})
sftpClient.on('close', () => {
  console.log('SFTP client emitted CLOSE')
})

const options = {
  host: '',
  port: '22',
  username: '',
  password: ''
};

// below infinite loop is to simulate large number of 
// connections in my production code
(async () => {
  while (true) {
    try {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(sftpClient.connect(options)), 1000))
    } catch {
      console.log('boom')
    }
  }
})()

process.on('exit', code => console.log(`Caught!. Exit code: ${code}`))

process.on('uncaughtException', (err, origin) => {
  console.error('Unhandled exception. Please handle!', err.stack || err)
  console.error(`Origin: ${JSON.stringify(origin)}`)
})

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err, promise) => {
  console.error('Unhandled promise rejection. Please handle!', promise, err.stack || err)
})

process.on('warning', (warning) => {
  console.warn(warning.name)
  console.warn(warning.message)
  console.warn(warning.stack)
})

process.on('rejectionHandled', (promise) => {
  console.log('rejectionHandled event triggered')
})
```

As you can see, it shouldn't escape the infinite loop unless there is an Error.
And it in fact does not for some iterations but eventually it escapes *(usually after <10 iterations)*. And the only log I see is

```
SFTP client emitted END
Caught!. Exit code: 0
```

On the SFTP server side I have the following limitations in the `sshd_config` file

```
MaxSessions 1
MaxStartups 1
```

I'm using:

- Node.js 12
- ssh2-sftp-client 4.1.0

**In brief, question:**

How can Node crash **without** any error events/stacktraces and **exit code 0**?

## Update #1

It was recommended in the comments to make a core dump of the process and analyse it.

How can I make a core dump on exit code 0?

If I make a core dump, what should I look for there?

## Update #2

Created an issue in the repository
https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client/issues/168

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with that loop?  That does not look correct.

Comment: I have an application which dies the same way. Of course in that application I close what I open. This code is a Minimal, Reproducible Example of the problem. So that anyone can copy the code, run it and see the issue.

Comment: Someone is calling process.exit

Comment: But the while loop makes no sense to me.  I'd like to know what you are trying to accomplish with it.  It looks like the wrong design that could exhaust all network resources.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I literally checked all the dependencies of dependencies. There is no `process.exit` anywhere. Unless some internal Node.js code is doing that.

Comment: @jfriend00 the issue is usually not happening on the first try. One has to run it multiple times. My assumption is at one point server cuts off the connections. That is why I have an infinite loop there. Again, it is an example and not a production code.

Comment: Take a core dump and check :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum `--abort-on-uncaught-exception` will not work here because there is not exception. Is there a way to make a core dump on exit code 0? What is the best way to do it?

Comment: But the loop keeps calling `sftpClient.connect()` over and over again forever.   The loop never stops, not even upon a successful connection. Can't possibly be the right design and could easily be a source of resource problems.  I see the library has its own retry options which are better designed.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm sorry for confusion. The question is not about coding style. The code in the question is an example of a strange behavior of Node.js that I'm trying to understand. The problem itself I think is not related to the fact that there is an opening connection in an infinite loop. But if it is related then I'd like to know how.

Comment: As I said already, you may be exhausting some kind of resource.  When unexplained things are happening, I fix any clearly wrong code first and retest.

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem is the SFTP I'm using gets consumed by a lot of different applications. None of them of course don't keep connections opened. And none of them is opening connections in an infinite loop. SFTP server gets under pressure and some of the applications crash exactly as the example in the question. I understand your point but my issue is not an infinite loop. Consider it as a PoC that Node can fail silently. Mystery, right?

Comment: There was this [open issue](https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client/issues/49) in the github repo for something that looks very similar to your problem. A possible fix is to make sure you have node +8 and the latest version of the module since they don't seem to know what is/was causing this.

Comment: @TudorConstantin this is exactly what I'm experiencing. But on Node.js 12 and the latest version of the package. Added this info to the question. Thank you for the issue.

Comment: have a look at [this code section](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/e8bd8fc2aadcc9adbb02e836f5d47ac11b4da0c7/lib/client.js#L916) in the ssh2 js module. Add some extra messages in your installed version of it and see whether that's the crash source...

Comment: @TudorConstantin I added a message in the `onExit` function and didn't get any output on crash :(

Comment: try adding messages as the first line in all of the `on...` functions, even in the `onReady()` (to make sure these messages are shown)

Comment: @TudorConstantin Yes, I already add a message on all `.emit` calls this library and down till the `ssh2-streams`. I see the messages but it doesn't help.

Comment: and what's the last message shown before node crashes?

Comment: @TudorConstantin the last msg I can get so far is from https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/blob/e8bd8fc2aadcc9adbb02e836f5d47ac11b4da0c7/lib/client.js#L313

Comment: created an issue in the repository https://github.com/theophilusx/ssh2-sftp-client/issues/168

Comment: I think this is better discussed on github not here. VTC as too broad

Comment: @Liam protest! The question is clear. It is about the Node.js behaviour. Nothing broad.

Comment: There are 23 comments on this question.....That's too many

Comment: @Liam 23 comments, because there is no one who can answer. It doesn't make the question too broad.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199793/discussion-on-question-by-leqada-how-node-js-silently-crashes-without-any-inform).

Answer (score 2):

This specific issue was being caused by the combination of the remote server dropping the TCP connection and the SSH2 library only raising an 'end' event with no 'error' event. This has been flagged as a bug in ssh2 and is listed in the issues for that module.

In the meantime, a work-around has been added to ssh2-sftp-client. Essentially, an additional 'end' listener has been added during the connection stage which will result in the connect promise being rejected if there is an end event raised. A new version of the package (v4.2.0) has been released which includes this fix.

For background information - part of the reason it is difficult to get consistent results when tracking down this issue is partly due to the MaxStartups setting of many SFTP servers (like openSSH). This setting can be a tuple of the form max:drop:full where max is the maximum allowed unauthenticated connections (connections which have not yet completed the handshake and authentication process), drop - percentage of connections to begin dropping after max is reached and full = number of unauthenticated connections to start dropping all connection attempts. The default value is often 10:30:60, which means allow 10 unauthenticated connections, start dropping 30% of them once there are more than 10 and drop all attempts once 60 unauthenticated connections occur. The drop value means that once more than 10 unauthenticated connections exist, attempts will be droped 30% of the time, which creates a somewhat random result in that each time you run your tests, different connections may be dropped. Servers will often just drop the connection without providing any additional information - you may or may not get a reset by peer error, depending on how the server does the dropping (often, you just get the end event and nothing more - no error raised).